# Node.JS reading file into string for external function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know the problem is how this is nested but I can not figure out how to correct it. This is a function that takes a parameter of a file name. It is suppose to grab the select statement and run the query. So instead of var reader = connection.reader("SELECT * FROM Inventory", []); it would look like var reader = connection.reader(function(inventory.sql), []);. But I can not see how to correct this!

```
var fs = require("fs");
var select_statement = "ss";
var sql_file = function(value) {
    var fileName = "./SQLs/inventory.sql";
    fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
                fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
                    var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
                    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
                        var data = buffer.toString("utf8", 0, buffer.length);
                        console.log(data);
                        fs.close(fd);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
};
module.exports.select_statement = select_statement;
module.exports.sql_file = sql_file;
    module.exports.sql_statement = sql_statement;
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but it looks like `fs.exists(fileName, function(exists)` and the following line `if (exists)` could cause an issue, why not just do `if(fs.open(fileName))`? Edit:: It looks like `fs.exists(path, callback)` [has been depricated and is only historical](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback).

Comment: The file exists, that is not the problem but I can not get it to return. The console out runs no problem but if I assign select_statement another value in right as I am reading the data select_statement still returns ss so I dont thing I am touching it. If any of that makes sense!

Comment: It looks like you are using quite a lot of callbacks. Try looking at the nodejs `fs` [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and see if the functions you are using can be changed to different functions.

Comment: Everything is up to date...

Comment: If someone can test this, it would be a great learning lesson because I have only been working with node for about a week.

Comment: I got it:fs = require('fs');
var sql_file = function(sql_file) {
    var select_statement

    fs.readFile("./SQLs/" + sql_file, "utf8", function(err, select_statement) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(select_statement);
    });
    return select_statement;

    return sql_file;
};
module.exports.sql_file = sql_file;
module.exports.select_statement = select_statement;

Comment: 'readFile()' is an asynchronous function. Use callback to get the file content instead of using `return` statement.